# Change font size in products listing pages in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to reduce the font size of the text inside the table so I can fit in more columns. Is there a hook I can use or do I need to modify wordpress/woocommerce's core? In that case, which css or template file do i need to change?[image: woocommerce-products-listing-page]

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `current_screen` hook

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_admin_listing_custom_styles' );
function my_admin_listing_custom_styles() {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'edit' == $current_screen->base && 'product' == $current_screen->post_type) {
        // Run some code, only on the admin products listing page for e.x add css style
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        a.row-title {font-size: 18px !important;}
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `admin_print_styles` hook to output custom CSS - in this case I've used the suffix `-edit.php` (which is the unique hook for the posts table screen). I also check the current post type is `product`, otherwise the CSS would output for pages, posts etc.

```
function wpse_184211_edit_products_style() {
    if ( get_current_screen()->post_type === 'product' ) {
        ?>

<style>
    .column-purpose {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>

<?php
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit.php', 'wpse_184211_edit_products_style' );
```

The CSS is an example - just inspect/check out the source code of the page and you'll see which class names/selectors you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an custom CSS sheet to your admin and style things however you like.

1. Create a new CSS document in your theme folder called `admin-style.css` and add your rules there. For example:

   ```
   .wp-list-table .row-title,
   .wp-list-table th,
   .wp-list-table td,
   .row-actions {
       font-size: 11px !important;
   }
   ```
2. Add the following code to your `functions.php` file:

   ```
   function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
       wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
       wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
   }
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
   ```

This avoids modifying the core, is child theme friendly, and allows you to easily modify other styles inside the admin as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the price font, price size, price color, with the Woo Product Price Styler plugin, the link is https://codecanyon.net/item/woo-product-price-styler/15730651

Comment: Welcome on WPSE Stathis and thanks for trying to help! Anyway, please have a look at how to write a good answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer as right now this is a link only answer that is of limited help.